# MySQL: How to restructure this code to eliminate adding and deleting intermediate colums

Tags: mysql, optimization

How do I update the following code so it's not adding and then deleting columns?

This code calculates the values for a numeric column (named "LengthFloat") from a column with values such as "3 yards" (named "Length").

```
alter table sometable add Value float;
alter table sometable add Units varchar(15);

Update sometable
   set Value = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Length, ' ', 1), ' ', -1),
       Units = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Length, ' ', 2), ' ', -1);

update sometable 
   set LengthFloat = case Units
      when 'yards' then Value*3
      when 'yard' then Value*3
      when 'feet' then Value
      when 'foot' then Value
   end;

alter table sometable drop column Value;
alter table sometable drop column Units;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code should be left as is.

The only other suggested answer that describes another method (using a View) is so terribly inefficient it has to be rejected (see the comments there).

Answer (score 0):

```
drop view  if exists  sometable_with_value_units;

create view           sometable_with_value_units as
select  id,
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Length, ' ', 1), ' ', -1) as value,
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Length, ' ', 2), ' ', -1) as units
  from  sometable;

select  id,
        case units
          when 'yards' then value * 3
          when 'yard'  then value * 3
          when 'feet'  then value
          when 'foot'  then value
        end as feet
  from  sometable_with_value_units;
```

Please see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed7ca1/3

Comment: When I try to update that to do the table update I need I get an error.

Comment: The base table, and the view (which synthesizes `value` in random `unit`s), and the select (which synthesizes consistent `feet`) all offer `id`. Just JOIN the base table with the select, `ON id`, when updating. Better, keep a sensible column, like `feet` or `meters` (not `barns`, that's for area measure), so you don't have to synthesize crazy intermediate results at all. Make it a new, permanent column, or put it in some adjunct table you can JOIN with.

Comment: I got the join to work.  For some reason this runs EXTREMELY slowly.  It wasn't finishing so I killed it, and then I had it run on just the first 1,000 rows.  That took 65 seconds (!!!).  Looking at the task manager, during this time the CPU was running at 28% (nearly all of it mysql), memory usage was at 44%, and disk usage hovered between 0% and 4%, usually at 0%.   I have already optimized my.cfg to replace their ridiculous values, so my 12GB of ram is utilized better.

Comment: The original code processes around 82.000 rows in 12 seconds.  There is clearly something wrong with the above method.  While it technically works (dropping/adding columns is not required, as I requested), there is something very wrong with its efficiency.

Comment: Post the EXPLAIN plan. You have a primary key on ID, right? Doing an equijoin without unique index would be crazy. The sqlfiddle mentioned `id integer primary key,` because that seemed the obvious thing to do.

Comment: Yes, the base table has a primary key ID that is indexed.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is possible to fiddle around with length expressions.  But it is painful in SQL.  Instead...

I would step back and decide which units to use.  I would probably pick the metric system.  For example, I might pick "meter" for all lengths, not kilometer, not Angstrom, not foot, not furlong, not barn, not light-year.  (OK, if the app dealt with astronomy, I might use light-year.)  Then I would do conversions in the app, not the database.  I would not be adding and dropping columns except in extreme situations.

Comment: I don't have any control over the way the data comes in.

Comment: Are other doing `INSERTs` directly into the database?  Or do you have an app receiving the data?  Hopefully the latter.  It is usually better to cleanse the data _before_ inserting into the database.

Comment: The database is as-is, from my point of view.  I'm preparing it for data mining.

Comment: OK, Insert into "staging" table(s), then use SQL to clean up the data before copying into the "real" table(s).